# Email to case routing address wont create Case in salesforce

Tags: email, case, email2case

We have a scenario to create a email to case in salesforce.

After creating hte email to case foe the specific shared mailbox the user has verified the email.

I have provided the routing email to the IT team to configure to forward the email to the routing address.IT guy has set it up .

While testing it did not created the case in salesforce. To verify if the routing address was configured BY IT is correct I tried to send mail to the routing address directly still it wont create a Case in salesforce.

Kindly Advise on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this "out of the box" email to case or apex email services ?

Comment: @AaronWilfred On Demand Email to case

Comment: Try emailing the email to case directly. If that works the issue is either with the forward setup or between the email server and salesforce (tls 1.0?)

Comment: Is the email-to-case setup is okay? Are you able to see Cases created if you send email to the long email services addresses?

Comment: @SarojBera I tried that as well it did not create the record

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, it seems the issue is with Email-to-Case setup, not the routing. You can troubleshoot with this Salesforce [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003944&type=1).

**Troubleshooting Email-to-Case on Demand not creating new cases**

**Description**

Sending an email to your Salesforce Email-to-Case On Demand routing address does not create a case in your Salesforce org.

Before you can determine the root cause of this issue, you need to try a few things to see what exactly is causing these emails not to create new cases

When dealing with On-Demand Email to Case, you have 2 different email address for each Routing address. One is the actual email address that own and another one that is created in your Salesforce org for your email address called the Email Services address

To check, follow the paths below and go to the Routing Addresses section:

For Classic: Setup | Customize | Cases | Email-to-Case 
For Lightning: Setup | Feature Settings | Service | Email-to-Case |

**Step 1**

We need to find out if these sent emails reach Salesforce servers, to do this send an email to the Email-to-Case long Email Services address to confirm if cases are created.  Simply compose a new email and copy paste the long email services addresses and send the email with a Test or similar subject with a time stamp in the body of the email so it would be easier to identify the email. Wait a few seconds and then login to your Salesforce org and go to Cases tab and look for the new case.

**Step 2**

*A new case is created*

Check your email client settings to confirm that the forwarding is setup properly and all the emails sent to your Email-to-Case Routing Address are forwarded to the Email-to-Case Email Services Address.

*No new case is created*

**Note: This customization is only available in: Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Editions.

If no case is created then most probably it is a configuration issue rather than an email delivery or forwarding issue. You also need to check with your Salesforce Administrator to make see if it ever worked or stopped working at some point.

1. First thing to check would be to verify if the Automated Case User has access to all the record types used for the Email-to-Case configuration:

To do this, login to your Salesforce org with a Salesforce Administrator account
- We need to find out what record types are being used by each the routing addresses so simply click on Setup | Customize | Cases | Email-to-Case in the Routing Addresses section and click on each of the routing address names and take note of the Record type

- Next navigate to paths below and click on the username link in front of the Automated Case User to view the user detail page.

For Classic: Setup | Customize | Cases | Support Settings
For Lightning: Setup | Feature Settings | Service | Support Settings

We need to view that user's Profile and there are different ways to view it depending on your org settings

- On the Profile page for this user, scroll down to the Record Type Settings section and verify that all the Record Types used with Email to Case routing addresses are assigned to this profile for the Cases object. If not simply click on the [ Edit ] link in front of the Cases and add the necessary or all the record types.
- Click on Save and try to send another email and check to see if a case gets created

[image: User-added image]

**Step 3**

In addition, check the Automated Case User's mailbox for any failure emails received that explains why Email to Case failed to create a case in salesforce. The failure email notifications will be sent from support@salesforce.com as its sender and will give a short explanation of the issue, for instance the name of the Validation Rule or Trigger that prevent the email from creating a case due to a missing value for a required field on the Case page layout.

**Step 4**

You can use the information in Step 3 above to check the settings in your org to find the problem.

1- For instance, start with checking for any Validation Rules, Workflow Rules and Triggers.
If you encounter an error message, confirm if it’s related to a validation rule. If it does, deactivate the rule for a minute and try to create the case using the Email-to-Case Service Email address.

2- Check for any required fields that could possible prevent the email to create a case. An email sent to the Email to Case routing address would only contain values for certain fields. You can see these fields under Case Settings in the Email-to-Case Routing Information page
The Case Priority field, Case Origin, and Case Record Type values are prepopulated once the email hits the Salesforce server based on your Case Settings. Any other required fields on the Case page layout would cause problems. You can try and create a case manually to replicate the scenario and leave the Contact and Account information blank.

3- You can also run a Debug log to see what Workflow and/or Triggers are being triggered during the process of creating a case.
- Setting up Debug Logs

**Step 5**

Check any Custom Case text fields for default values that exceed the character limit for the field.  For example if the default character limit value of Text Area field is 255 characters and the default value is more than 255 characters case can be created manually as the field truncates, however when creating cases through the API such as with Email to Case the case creation fails with an error similar to  Error ID : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (-401266195)]